# On-click event display data on heap map in highcharts

Tags: express, highcharts

[This image contains details about the number of projects was uploaded by the particular user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gzgB.png)

I am using heapmap highchart to display project details of a user.

```
on Y-axis => represents week of the days which ranges from 0 to 6
eg. Mon = 0, Tue= 1,....Sun=6

on X-axis => represents months, which ranges from 0 to 11
eg. Jan = 0, Feb = 1, ... Dec = 11
```

Data format

```
 X   Y  Data
[0  ,1  , 3]
```

Suppose, 3 projects was uploaded by a user on monday in the month of January.
When I click on that 3 on heap map then it should display a pop box,

```
which should include project name,date and time
eg. Project Name : image recognition
    Date : Uploaded on Jan 4,2019
    Time : 10:04:00
```

In this I have hardcoded the data.
https://jsfiddle.net/k9hyfjmL/

This code retrieve data from mysql database and populates on heap map, which indicates number of projects was uploaded by a user.

```
$(document).on('click', '.click_once', function()
       {

            $.ajax(
                {
                url: '/profile/heap_map_data',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(response) 
                {
                        var chart_data = [];
                        var skip_1st_data = 1;
                        var take_Data_upto = 0;
                        for (var i = 0, len = response.length; i < len; i++)
                        {   if(skip_1st_data == 1)
                        {
                                skip_1st_data = 2;
                        }
                        else{
                                take_Data_upto = take_Data_upto + 1;
                                chart_data.push(response[i]);

                                if(take_Data_upto == 31)
                                {
                                        break;
                                }
                        }

                        }
                        console.log(chart_data)
                        Highcharts.chart('heap_map_chart', 
                        {

                                chart: 
                                {
                                        type: 'heatmap',
                                        marginTop: 40,
                                        marginBottom: 80,
                                        plotBorderWidth: 1,
                                },


                                title: 
                                {
                                        text: 'Project Details'
                                },

                                xAxis: 
                                {
                                        categories: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
                                },

                                yAxis: 
                                {
                                        categories: ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun'],
                                        title: null
                                },



                                colorAxis: 
                                {
                                        min: 0,
                                        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
                                        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                                },

                                legend: 
                                {
                                        align: 'right',
                                        layout: 'vertical',
                                        margin: 0,
                                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                                        y: 25,
                                        symbolHeight: 280
                                },

                                tooltip: 
                                {
                                        formatter: function () 
                                        {
                                                return  + this.point.value + ' <b> project was uploaded on ' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + ' date, 2019' + '<br /> click to view more' ;
                                        }
                                },

                                series: [
                                {

                                        borderWidth: 1,
                                        data: chart_data,

                                        dataLabels: 
                                        {
                                                enabled: true,
                                                color: '#000000'
                                        }
                                }]

                        }); 


                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                        console.log('jqXHR:');
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        console.log('textStatus:');
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log('errorThrown:');
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                        alert(errorThrown);
                } 

                });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `point.events.click` function to display some more information in another HTML element:

```
series: [{
    point: {
        events: {
            click: function() {
                document.getElementById('moreInfo').innerText =
                    'value: ' + this.value;
            }
        }
    },

    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p261zg9d/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.point.events.click

Comment: Thank you for help. I have implemented and it's working but I don't want to show x and y values when it is clicked. I have the data from database which returns project name,project_id,date and time of uploading. suppose on Friday, July 2019 I have uploaded 3 projects and on heap map it displays the number of projects on particular day and month but when user clicks on that number of projects then it should display project name, date and time of upload and I have no idea where to store these data in heap map and when user clicks then based on project_id I would like to show projects details.

Comment: for example [https://jsfiddle.net/gvh69b2k/]           this expands on click and shows hidden data

Comment: Hi @Ctrl pulse Tab, Your jsfiddle does not work. You can store your additional data as point properties.